# Using index location values from one df to subset another df with same but repititive index values

Tags: r, subset

I have two dataframes:
df1:

```
i1<-c(0,1,2,3,4) 
loci<-c(2,2,3,2,3) 
df1<-data.frame(i1,loci)
```

df2:

```
i1<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4) 
x<-c(343,434,23,232,3,34,422,245,2,2,2,4,553,234,532,234,23,34,23)
y<-c(33,545,88,8,88,86,4565,3434,234,34,545,234,2343,35,4,5,35,45,55) 
df2<-data.frame(i1,x,y)
```

I want to achieve this-

```
i1<-c(0,1,2,3,4) 
x<-c(434,422,2,234,34) 
y<-c(545,4565,234,35,45) 
df3<-data.frame(i1,x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys !
All the options work pretty fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `loci` variable in `df2` which gives the row index within each group by `i1`, and then do a `right_join()` to `df1`, here is an option with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(i1) %>%
  mutate(loci = row_number()) %>% 
  right_join(df1) %>%
  select(-loci)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# Groups: i1 [5]

#      i1     x     y
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0   434   545
# 2     1   422  4565
# 3     2     2   545
# 4     3   234    35
# 5     4    34    45
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches. The `dplyr` way is close to Psidom so ignore if redundant.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="i1") %>% group_by(i1) %>% slice(loci[1])
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: i1 [5]
# 
#      i1  loci     x     y
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0     2   434   545
# 2     1     2   422  4565
# 3     2     3     2   545
# 4     3     2   234    35
# 5     4     3    34    45

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, on="i1"][,.SD[loci[1]], by=i1]
#    i1 loci   x    y
# 1:  0    2 434  545
# 2:  1    2 422 4565
# 3:  2    3   2  545
# 4:  3    2 234   35
# 5:  4    3  34   45
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `merge` and `ave` from `base R`.  With `ave`, we create a sequence column grouped  by 'i1', and then `merge` with 'df1'

```
dfN <- merge(df1, transform(df2, loci= ave(i1, i1, FUN = seq_along)))[-2]
```